# Can a CSS code/file load JS code/file?

Tags: javascript, css

We know that using *Javascript* we can load *CSS* files.

But, can we load *Javascript* files or run *Javascript* code using *CSS*?

If yes, how? Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: No, luckily not. There used to be something like this in older IEs but it was a security nightmare and has gone extinct.

Comment: No. Delete this question. Any what purpose would this have? T

Comment: @Leeish It's just my curiosity... I just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your end goal is, but have you checked out the CSS variables that are coming (I think they just hit FF nightlies)? The other thing I guess I would ask is what you mean exactly by "loading" vs. "running" JS? Couldn't you in theory pull down a JS file by referencing it as an image or some such? I can't imagine it would help you much, but...

Comment: @JTrana It's just like an experiment... I couldn't imagine that such a thing is possible (even only in old IE versions). I don't plan to use this in a real application, but I want to know if this is possible or not. Or which are the solutions...

Comment: So do you want to actually execute JS somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think IE and firefox supports **CSS expressions** which probably you may think of. Something like

```
width:expression(document.body.clientWidth > 800? "800px": "auto" );
```

but these are [really bad things and you should avoid this](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/)

Also you should **[avoid CSS expression](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_expressions)** as much as you can.

You can use the CSS like this:

```
body {
  behavior:url(xyz.htc);
}
```

and now in the xyz.htc file you can write like:

```
<PUBLIC:COMPONENT TAGNAME="xss">
   <PUBLIC:ATTACH EVENT="ondocumentready" ONEVENT="ABC()" LITERALCONTENT="false"/>
</PUBLIC:COMPONENT>
<SCRIPT>
   function ABC() 
   {
     alert("Message");
   }
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Does Requiring  a `htc` file work on newer browsers or only in the old ones?

Comment: @イオニカビザウ:- Its on the old ones but you can check it on the new ones! Also I suggest you to read the expressions link which I have linked in my answer. That would help you!

Comment: Tested in Firefox and Chromium, but it doesn't work. Anyway, interesting information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not run Javascript or import Javascript into CSS... not that you would ever need to.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The closest thing I can think of is Netscape 4 had a thing called JavaScript Style Sheets (JSSS)

http://www.w3.org/Submission/1996/1/WD-jsss-960822